# Ability for AWX user with limited permission to edit notifications settings on templates

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

Created a user in AWX with admin access to only one project. When the user creates a new templates, he does not have access to enable/disable notifications.

While the system administrator have access to notifications...
[image: admin user notification settings]

The new user does not have access to notifications....
[image: basic user no notification settings]

I was looking for a way to grant permissions to an user to edit success and failure notification settings. Even having organization level **notification admin** permissions won't give access to the template notification settings.

Is this intended? Am i missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: This is a known issue where the notification tab does not show up. You should be able to toggle them via the API. - [source](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/2949#issuecomment-448607859)